# Git, undo commit since added .gitignore

Tags: git

I pushed a commit by accident without adding the gitignore (so it pushed up all the node moudles ect..). How can I undo this with the gitingore now added and the accidentally files pushed removed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wrong commit is the last you can do simply

```
git reset HEAD^     # <---- remove the last commit keeping all files
git add .           # add all files from removed commit + new .gitignore
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

---

UPDATE

Or if your commit in the middle of a tree:

```
git rebase -i SOME_HASH_BEFORE_WRONG_COMMIT
```

Set "edit" on the wrong commit. When git stops on the commit then edit your gitignore (or get it from `git stash`) and

```
git reset HEAD^
git add .
git reset --continue
```